# SCons delete $TARGET on failure of any Action

Tags: scons

Is there a way to emulate Make's [`.DELETE_ON_FAILURE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html) behavior?  If I have a builder that executes a series of Actions to produce a target, I would expect them to operate atomically. If an earlier Action produces an (incomplete) file, and a later action fails to modify it, I would like the target file to be deleted, instead of remaining in its incomplete state.

Consider this SConstruct file:

```python
def example(target, source, env):
    raise Exception('failure')
    # more processing that never happens...

action_list = [
    Copy('$TARGET', '$SOURCE'),
    Chmod('$TARGET', 0755),
    example,
]

Command(
    action = action_list,
    target = 'foo.out',
    source = 'foo.in',
)
```

If the `example` action fails, `foo.out` still exists, because the first two actions were successful. However, it is incomplete.

Interestingly, running `scons` again causes is to again retry to build `foo.out`, even though it exists in the filesystem.

Comment: I dont know of any sort of rollback/atomic feature like that in SCons. You may try emailing the scons users list: scons-users@scons.org

Comment: @Brady Thanks for the feedback. Indeed, I did cross-post this on the mailing list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, what you are looking for is [GetBuildFailures](http://www.scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-user/ch09s04.html).

Expanding on your example to include this feature...

```python
import atexit
import os

def delete_on_failure():
    from SCons.Script import GetBuildFailures
    for bf in GetBuildFailures():
        if os.path.isfile(bf.node.abspath):
            print 'Removing %s' % bf.node.path
            os.remove(bf.node.abspath)
atexit.register(delete_on_failure)

def example(target, source, env):
    raise Exception('failure')
    # more processing that never happens...

action_list = [
    Copy('$TARGET', '$SOURCE'),
    Chmod('$TARGET', 0755),
    example,
]

Command(
    action = action_list,
    target = 'foo.out',
    source = 'foo.in',
)
```

Which when run produces the following...

```
>> scons --version
SCons by Steven Knight et al.:
    script: v2.3.4, 2014/09/27 12:51:43, by garyo on lubuntu
    engine: v2.3.4, 2014/09/27 12:51:43, by garyo on lubuntu
    engine path: ['/usr/lib/scons/SCons']
Copyright (c) 2001 - 2014 The SCons Foundation

>> tree 
.
├── foo.in
└── SConstruct

0 directories, 2 files

>> scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
Copy("foo.out", "foo.in")
Chmod("foo.out", 0755)
example(["foo.out"], ["foo.in"])
scons: *** [foo.out] Exception : failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Action.py", line 1065, in execute
    result = self.execfunction(target=target, source=rsources, env=env)
  File "/path/to/SConstruct", line 13, in example
    raise Exception('failure')
Exception: failure
scons: building terminated because of errors.
Removing foo.out

>> tree
.
├── foo.in
└── SConstruct

0 directories, 2 files
```

Comment: Very nice, I will definitely try this Monday. Thanks.

Comment: Did this answer your question?  If so can you mark this as the answer?  If not, let me know what you are missing.